# How to use $Count in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

I have a collections as bellow:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c2493935634e4300000000c"), "typeCall" : "Internal", "date" : "2018-12-27", "starttime" : "2018-12-27 15:55:43", "endtime" : "2018-12-27 15:55:46", "source" : "21000", "destination" : "22000", "duration" : "3", "billsec" : "0", "disposition" : "NO ANSWER", "channel" : "SIP/21000-00000018", "destinationchannel" : "SIP/22000-00000019", "uniqueid" : "1545900943.24" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c2498915634e4300000000d"), "typeCall" : "Internal", "date" : "2018-12-27", "starttime" : "2018-12-27 16:17:02", "endtime" : "2018-12-27 16:17:05", "source" : "21000", "destination" : "22000", "duration" : "2", "billsec" : "0", "disposition" : "NO ANSWER", "channel" : "SIP/21000-0000001a", "destinationchannel" : "SIP/22000-0000001b", "uniqueid" : "1545902222.26" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c2498e25634e4300000000e"), "typeCall" : "Internal", "date" : "2018-12-27", "starttime" : "2018-12-27 16:18:23", "endtime" : "2018-12-27 16:18:26", "source" : "21000", "destination" : "22000", "duration" : "3", "billsec" : "0", "disposition" : "NO ANSWER", "channel" : "SIP/21000-0000001c", "destinationchannel" : "SIP/22000-0000001d", "uniqueid" : "1545902303.28" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c24990d5634e4300000000f"), "typeCall" : "Internal", "date" : "2018-12-27", "starttime" : "2018-12-27 16:19:05", "endtime" : "2018-12-27 16:19:09", "source" : "21000", "destination" : "22000", "duration" : "3", "billsec" : "0", "disposition" : "NO ANSWER", "channel" : "SIP/21000-0000001e", "destinationchannel" : "SIP/22000-0000001f", "uniqueid" : "1545902345.30" }
```

How to export the table as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please post the expected JSON output instead screenshot

Comment: This is JSON Output examples: `{ "_id" : "21000", "date" : "2018-12-27", "totalIncomingCall" : "0", "totalOutgoingCall" : "0", "totalDuration" : "0", "totalBillsec" : "0" } ` @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: Not getting your question